# Why is my Flask site not displaying the correct information from the database?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Here is my repository:

​

https://github.com/normandantzig1/artshow.git

​

​I am not getting the expected results when I run my Flask site

​

I am trying to build for a small project. I am in Bash with a virtualenv.

​

When I go to my my Artshow route for the site, I see "This is the array: submissions" and "says:". Says is repeated 11 times. First, I expect to see a string showing the contents of my submission query where "submissions" is. Second, I expect to see the username of the submitter, "says": and body of the submission repeated 5 times (because there are 5 rows in the submission table).

​

​Example:

The site should show: Tom says Here is a cat picture

​

I am new to flask and sqlalchemy. Did I pass the submissions right in the routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In future, please show the relevant code in your question itself.

The problem is in your artshow function, where you have this code;

```
return render_template('artshow.html', title='artshow', submissions='submissions')
```

Here you are sending the literal string "submissions" to the template, and you iterate over it (count how many letters it has). Instead, you should be sending the `submissions` variable you defined in the previous line:

```
return render_template('artshow.html', title='artshow', submissions=submissions)
```